# How do i get my txt file named with 2 user inputs

Tags: c++

My txt file created of each month has to be in the format as follow: "expense_month_year.txt".
Also, i can't get my output file to become txt file.
Please advice

```
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string month;
    int year;

    ofstream file;

    cout << "Please enter the month." << endl;
    getline(cin,month);

    cout << "Please enter the year." << endl;
    cin >> year;

    //Example of txt file has to be named as follow "expenses_January_2017"
    file.open(month.c_str() );
    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can create the filename string using `std::istringstream`

Comment: Note that it's often easier to use `argv` arguments to `main` than to do this 1980s style with "`ENTER NAME`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)

```
#include <sstream>


string month
int year;

stringstream filename;

cin >> month;
cin >> year;

filename << "expenses_" << month << "_" << year;
ofstream file(filename.str());

// . . .
```